# Validation is preventing the record being created using nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a association

```rb
class DeliveryVehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :compartments
  validates :compartments, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attribtues_for :compartments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In the controller. I am trying to create the record using

```rb
DeliveryVehicle.create!(name: "Ford", compartments_attributes: {slug: 'comp1', length: 2})
```

The above creation is throwing an error saying the compartments should exist for a delivery vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there is a typo?

`accepts_nested_attribtues_for`, should be:
`accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: Additionally, `compartments_attributes` should be an **Array**, because this is a `has_many` association. See the "one-to-many" documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html